# Connection to SQL Server with embedded clr procedures

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

My app use sql server and I want to use internal functions as stored procedures. Is it possible or maybe there are other libraries that enable such integration ?
I know that I may create separate assembly with crl stored procedures and use it with sql server, but this library will run in SQL server process and won't be possible to get data from my running app, that will be in another process.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to attach directly to another process as the only option is as you described: create an Assembly in SQL Server, and that Assembly will run in SQL Server's CLR host in it's own App Domain. Also, the version of the CLR might be different depending on what version of SQL Server is being used. SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2 are statically linked to CLR v 2.0 and the .NET Framework versions that use CLR v 2.0: 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5.

However, there are probably ways to do inter-process communication that can cross App Domain boundaries and possibly even CLR version (and host?) boundaries. I have seen some code that is .NET wrappers for COM-visible code sitting outside of SQL Server and that works, even if not an "elegant" setup (as it might require the Assembly loaded into SQL Server to be marked as `UNSAFE`).